# You Don't Have Permission to Upload Files Error in kcfinder

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I Use the `ckeditor` with `KCfinder` to upload images inside text editor content, but when I click on `"Send it to the Server"` Button, it returns an alert says:

> You Don't Have Permission to Upload Files

Do you Have any idea why this message shown? and how to solve this problem? 
Thank you